# Como gerenciar a prop "disabled" dos botões de um multi step form com Formik?

Tags: react, formulário, validação, formik

O **Formik** fornece uma prop chamada **isValid**, que já resolve o problema de definir quando o botão do formulário deve estar desabilitado. O problema é que isso aparente não funciona em um multi step form, pois o **isValid** da **step** atual do formulário sofre interferência das propriedades das demais **steps**. Com isso dito, gostaria de saber como posso manipular a habilitação dos botões sem precisar recorrer ao uso de **estados** no **React**.

Index.jsx:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Formik } from 'formik';

import nameSchema from '../../schema/nameSchema'
import emailSchema from '../../schema/emailSchema'

import Email from './Email';
import Name from './Name';

const WizardForm = () => {
  const [step, setStep] = useState(1)

  const nextStep = () => {
    setStep(step + 1)
  }

  const prevStep = () => {
    setStep(step - 1)
  }

  const currentStepSchema = () => {
   if(step === 1) {
     return nameSchema
   }

   if(step === 2) {
     return emailSchema
   }
  }

  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={{ name: '', email: '' }}
      validationSchema={currentStepSchema()}
    >
      {
        ({ isValid }) => (
          <>
            <Name
              isValid={isValid}
              nextStep={nextStep}
              step={step}
            />

            <Email
              isValid={isValid}
              prevStep={prevStep}
              nextStep={nextStep}
              step={step}
            />
          </>
        )
      }
    </Formik>
  );
}

export default WizardForm;
```

Name.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import { ErrorMessage, Field, Form } from 'formik';

const Name = ({ step, nextStep, isValid }) => {
  if (step !== 1) {
    return null
  }

  return (
    <Form>
      <Field
        name='name'
        type='text'
        placeholder='type your name'
      />

      <div>
        <ErrorMessage name='name' />
      </div>

      <button disabled={!isValid} onClick={nextStep}>Next</button>
    </Form>
  );
}

export default Name;
```

Email.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { ErrorMessage, Field, Form } from 'formik';

const Email = ({ step, nextStep, prevStep, isValid }) => {
  if (step !== 2) {
    return null
  }

  return (
    <Form>
      <Field
        name='email'
        type='text'
        placeholder='type your Email'
      />

      <div>
        <ErrorMessage name="email" />
      </div>

      <button onClick={prevStep}>Prev</button>
      <button disabled={!isValid} onClick={nextStep}>Next</button>
    </Form>
  );
}

export default Email;
```

nameSchema.js:

```
import * as Yup from 'yup'

export default Yup.object().shape({
  name: Yup.string().min(2).required()
})
```

emailSchema.js:

```
import * as Yup from 'yup'

export default Yup.object().shape({
  name: Yup.string().email().required()
})
```

Como podem observar nesse exemplo, a validação do click funciona perfeitamente na step do Name, mas não funciona no Email, pois existe uma interferência das propriedades vindas do Name